# How can I execute XPath queries on DOMElements using PHP?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, element

I'm trying to do Xpath queries on DOMElements but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code

```
<html>
    <div class="test aaa">
        <div></div>
        <div class="link">contains a link</div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="test bbb">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="link">contains a link</div>
    </div>
</html>
```

What I'm doing is this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents("file.html");
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class,'test')]");
if (!$entries->length > 0) {
    echo "Nothing\n";
} else {
  foreach ($entries as $entry) {
      $link = $xpath->query('/div[@class=link]',$entry);
      echo $link->item(0)->nodeValue;
      // => PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object
  }
}
```

Everything works fine up to `$xpath->query('/div[@class=link], $entry);`. I don't know how to use Xpath on a particular DOMElement ($entry).

**How can I use xpath queries on DOMElement?**

Comment: A good answer (other than a guess) cannot be given unless you provide the XML document (as small as possible) on which these XPath expressions are evaluated. You may have a default namespace and this could explain the result. Also, note that `//div.link` is an *absolute* XPath expression while you want to evaluate a *relative* XPath expression against each `$entry`. So, it would rather be: `.//div.link`

Comment: I assume your HTML is XHTML and totally valid XHTML at that?

Comment: @Orbling: No need for that, he's using the `loadHTML` method.

Comment: @Jon: Well, still, it'll generate a batch load of warnings if there are invalid bits.

Comment: @Dimitre: stop removing the xpath tag from questions you don't like.

Comment: @Dimitre: bring this up on Meta if you want to continue the discussion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to mix CSS selectors with XPath.  You want to be using a predicate (`[...]`) looking at the value of the `class` attribute.

For example, your `//div.link` might look like `//div[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' link ')]`.

Secondly, within the loop you try to make a query with a context node then ignore that by using an absolute location path (it starts with a slash).

**Updated** to reflect changes to the question:

Your second XPath expression (`/div[@class=link]`) is still a) absolute, and b) has an incorrect condition. You want to be asking for matching elements relative to the specified context node (`$entry`) with the `class` attribute having a *string value* of `link`.

So `/div[@class=link]` should become something like `div[@class="link"]`, which searches children of the `$entry` elements (use `.//div[...]` or `descendant::div[...]` if you want to search deeper).

Comment: My mistake was indeed the incorrect condition with the missing quotes around "link". Thanks.